# 400 on second submit in form in angular

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

I have a problem with a form submit in Angular / .net Core.

I have a form, where the user can submit changes. The submit does a post on the .net core background. After that, the form is resetted.

So far so good, but after that it doesn't post anymore.

The problem seems to be with the form reset. If i exlude it, a second submit would work. Here is my (sample) code:

```
<form #frm="ngForm" id="frm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(frm.value, frm); frm.reset();">
            <input [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" name="selectedItem" type="text" />

            <button type="submit" class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised">
              <span class="mdc-button__label"><i class="material-icons">done</i></span>
            </button>
</form>
```

```
  onSubmit(formData, form: NgForm) {
    this.service.SetItem(formData, this.selectedItemTyp).subscribe(data => {
      this.reload(id);
    });
  }
```

```
  SetItem(param: object, table: string): Observable<any> {

    var data = {
      Item: param["selectedItem"]
    };

    return this.http.post('/api/item/SetItem', data).pipe(
      catchError(
        this.handleError('SetItem', [])
      )
    );
  }
```

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SetItem([FromBody]StatusBody parameter)
        {
            try
            {
                db.SetItem(parameter.Item);

                db.SaveChanges();

                return Ok("");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Ok(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

If i remove frm.reset(); in the component html, it works as expected.

Comment: You can use DevTools to compare JSON sent to the server in each case, it will give a clue.

Comment: 400 bad request means, either your payload,headers,request params is wrong, and i believe mostly its the payload(body) , since you are resetting it. Check this bug by comparing the payload in developer tools

Comment: Thanks, i found it...

Answer (score 0):

The model in the server side StatusBody ,you need to send that model object correctly , otherwise it's return 400.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was a parameter that was null after the first submit...

Thanks to all.